# org.json.JSONException: of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to color my mobile phone application with a background color like Facebook's blue background color. So what is the hexadecimal code of it ?

```
Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                        if (success) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(register.this, login.class);
                            register.this.startActivity(intent);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(register.this);
                            builder.setMessage("Register Failed")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

public RegisterRequest(String first_name, String last_name, String e_mail, String user_name, String date_of_birth, String gender, String password, String confirm_password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("first_name", first_name);
    params.put("last_name", last_name);
    params.put("e_mail", e_mail);
    params.put("user_name", user_name);
    params.put("date_of_birth", date_of_birth);
    params.put("gender", gender);
    params.put("password", password);
    params.put("confirm_password", confirm_password);

}
```

this is the reaponse

Comment: Well, what is the JSON received ? I would say that your response is not a correct JSON so the constructor throw this is exception saying that the String can't be converted into a JSONObject (wrong format)

Comment: response string is not in the JSON Format, what i think, check the response string whether it is in json format or not.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the content of `response`? (And it wouldn't hurt of you have a sentence ending in '?'. You're asking a _question_.)

Comment: Please provide the entire stack trace and json response

Comment: do you need the php file too?